# Is DELL's HP-P2507FWP PSU's 20-pin connector wiring non-standard?

Tags: power-supply, connector, atx

My old PC's ATX PSU died and I got a replacement in the form of a DELL 250W Power Supply model# [HP-P2507FWP](http://www.stuartconnections.com/en/power-supplies/2015-Dell-250W-ATX-Power-Supply-Unit-PSU-8X949-HPP2507FWP.html).

It has the exact set of connectors (except for an additional, unused, 6-pin connector), including the main [20-pin connector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATX#Power_supply) (also see this reference for [standard](http://pinouts.ru/Power/atxpower_pinout.shtml) v 1.x with 20 pin)

I plugged everything in, expecting my PC to come to life again, but while the green LED on the motherboard lights on as soon as I plug the power cord, nothing else happens when I press the ATX (momentary) power on button.

At first I thought that I ran into the infamous [Dell proprietary (non-standard) ATX design](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=339053), but when I compared the colors of the wires, they were **all identical**!

My next step is to actually measure voltages across the various pins to see whether indeed the colors match the documented voltage values but I still find it strange that I couldn't find any documentation or reference regarding the wiring of this particular PSU model.

More specifically, I have the following questions:

1. Why do two websites that used to sell this PSU, claim it as having a **24-pin** connector, not 20-pin? (one of the even has a photo of that 24-pin connector! and I can tell you with utmost certainty that mine has a 20-pin connector *and* the **HP-P2507FWP** original DELL label on it.
2. Why is DELL's wiring's color coding identical to a standard ATX, despite [the article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=339053) describing even the colors being different?
3. If *my particular* DELL PSU is standard... Are there additional plausible explanations for the fact that my PC won't respond to a power on signal?

Comment: [This problem](http://www.badcaps.net/forum/printthread.php?t=5750) description sounds very similar to yours. 

Could be [bad capacitors](http://www.badcaps.net/forum/showpost.php?p=54870&postcount=6)?

Comment: Indeed this turned out to be a problem of bad capacitors. Thank you! Please post as an answer so that I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you have described so far (including the confirmation of bad capacitors as the source of the problem and that now it works for you):

1. I don't know, but a 24-pin connector is really a 20-pin one with the CPU 4-pin connector appended to it. Some manufacturers (e.g. [Antec](http://www.silentpcreview.com/article260-page1.html)) actually ship their PSU with a 24-pin connector that can be converted to a 20+4 set by sliding one of each other (pretty clever if you ask me).
2. Because you happened to stumble on a standard DELL PSU connector?
3. Yes, [bad capacitors](http://www.badcaps.net/forum/printthread.php?t=5750). It's very common in those types of PSUs.